# Obstructions to Smith normal form of a special type

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a Smith normal form $S,$ and I want to have an $M \in SL(n, \mathbb{Z}),$ such that $M - I$ has SNF $S.$ Is this always possible? For a (potentially) somewhat harder question, what if I require that $M \in Sp(n, \mathbb{Z})$ (and again, I want to realize a God-given SNF).

Comment: No idea. There is a book called integral Matrices I've always wanted to own, I think by Newman. http://www.amazon.com/Integral-Matrices-Monographs-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/0125178506  Some of this material becomes important for quadratic forms

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-094-01/S0002-9939-1985-0781052-8/ could be good for something

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you mean $n>1$. For $n=2$, the matrix $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1-r(1+rs) & r\\
-r(1+s+rs) & 1+r \end{array}\right]$ has determinant 1, and $A-I$ has SNF with diagonal $(r,rs)$.

Comment: So, presumably that resolves the $SL(n)$ question for any even $n,$ by using this construction in blocks. Does this matrix come from somewhere, or did it just occur to you?

Comment: And it does the $Sp(2n, \mathbb{Z}) case, since $SL(2) = Sp(2).$ Truly you are wise in the ways of science.

Comment: The matrix came from solving the equations $ad-bc=1$, gcd$(a-1,b,c,d-1)=r$, $(a-1)(d-1)-bc=r^2s$. I made the simplifying assumption $b=d=r$, $a-1=\alpha r$, $d-1=\delta r$ and solved.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer for the $Sl(n,Z)$ is positive if $n>1$. 
Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix, we ask if there's a $M$ such that $M-I$ is equivalent to $D$.($A$ is equivalent to $B$ if there are invertible $P,Q $such that  $PAQ=B$.)
This is same as asking if there's an $R$ in $SL(n,Z)$ s.t. $D+R$ is in $Sl(n,Z)$.(Reasoning:$ P(M-I)Q=PMQ-PQ$, and $PMQ$ is in $Sl(n,Z)$, $PQ$ is in $SL(n,Z)$, (neglecting the $\pm1$, which is not important)).

For any $P,Q$ in $Sl(n,Z)$, $D+R$ in $SL(n,Z)$ is same as $P(D+R)Q$ is in $SL(n,Z)$, thus we can replace $D$ with $PDQ$, so we can consider $PDQ$ to be the the follwoing matrix: the entries right above the diagonal are $d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_{n-1}$, the $(n,1)$ entry is $d_n$, all other entries are $0$. Now let $PRQ$ be the identity matrix but only the $(n,1)$ entry being $-d_n$. This matrix $R$ is the one we are looking for.

In this argument, $D$ is not necessarily a diagonal matrix, actually $D$ can be any integer matrix, because we can use SNF to transform it to a diagonal matrix.

Conclusion: if $n>1$, any $n$ by $n$ integer matrix  is the difference of a pair matrices in $Sl(n,Z)$.

Comment: I think the conclusion must have been a well-known fact: $SL(n,Z)-SL(n,z)=Mat(n,Z)$, for $n>1$.